# Views, Grouping by various levels of granularity in a date field?

Tags: entities, datetime, views

I'd like to group a nodes in a view by date, but more specifically, I'd like Grouping field Nr.1 to be year and Grouping field Nr.2 to be the month.

Possible?

[image: Grouping field description pop up]

### At current the test view looks like this:

[image: Test query view]

### I'd like it to look more like this

### 2015

November

- ibh Persto Torqueo Vel

October

- Commoveo Macto Premo Vel

September

- Ad Adipiscing Meus Nutus Tego Torqueo

### 2012

December

- Antehabeo Decet Pala Populus

April

- Quadrum Si Suscipit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I got it.

### **Step 1: Add two new date formats**

I set up two new date formats: Month only and Year only

[image]

---

### **Step 2: Query the date date field twice under the new formats**

Add the Publication Date field twice in these newly created formats

[image: Date Field year only][image]

---

### **Step 3: Apply the proper grouping to the view**

Here's how I grouped it....
[image]

---

### **And finally, the results**

Below, albeit poorly formatted, I have two two years of 2015 and 2014 with sub divided months.

(For some reason, what ever the last grouped field is encapulated in . I tried playing with the formatting but no luck. However, I've worked out my logic here.)

[image: Result]